# Jetbrains REST API to move projects

Tags: teamcity, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to use the TeamCity REST API of JetBrains as shown in http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API

I was specifically looking for a way to "Move" projects between project hierarchies. Obviously you can use the web user interface to Move a project however I need to automate this.

The REST API only talks about adding build steps, agents and so on. Is there a specific API to move a job? I tried using the Chrome Developer tools to see what happens when you move the project in a web UI but could not detect anything.

Comment: You are mixing terminology and some that isn't TeamCity terminology, do you want to move a project in the project hierarchy, or move a  build configuration from one project to another? FYI, the `application.wadl` file hosted on each TeamCity instance explained at the top of that link shows you everything you can do, although it is a little hard to understand.

Comment: Edited question to use word "Project hierarchy" instead of containers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application.wadl has methods to do most of these although the confluence page itself does not necessarily document every single feature.

To achieve this project move between different hierarchies, you had to do a PUT request to

```
http://$host/guestAuth/app/rest/projects/id:$project_to_edit/parentProject
```

with a JSON snippet (or an XML) of the form

```
{"id" : $new_parent_id}
```

Comment: If anyone else finds it, you might need to remove `guestAuth` from the URI, depending on your authentication type.